# A world without horse

Tags: alternate-history, civilization, horses

Imagine that in ancient times, long before homo sapiens even exist, a certain, or a chain of certain events caused Equidae (horse family) creatures to go extinct, globally. So since the beginning of homo sapiens history, there is no horse, mule, donkey, and zebra. How would the world's history change? Note, only horse family creatures go extinct, there are still elephants, cows, oxen and other creatures human uses for labor still exists. So we still have the elephant calvary and ox-pulled plow. Also, just to clarify, there are NO horse girls in this world.

[This question is inspired by the setting of Uma Musume Pretty Derby, where instead of horses you got super rare horse girls who are the reincarnation of famous horses in our world]

Comment: *"How would the world's history change?"* You are introducing a major change very early. It is safe to say that history would change beyond recognition.

Comment: Rejiggling 6000 years of history is not really something that can be summarised in a reasonable answer here. If your question requires an entire book to be written to answer it, then your question is not a good fit for stack exchange! Narrow things down a bit. Ask something more specific.

Comment: A simpler answer would be "a whole lot of stuff in several aspects of society, the economy and military combat throughout history would change, particularly so in terms of moving stuff around and moving fast in the earlier technological stages", and a more complete answer probably doesn't fit here. It'd be better to look at certain events or smaller time periods, because right now it's a "my world lacks something that played a major role in human history, how does history change?" type of question.

Answer (score 3):

It'd have a pretty big impact. Although from what I understand oxen and other domesticated animals are still around, it would drastically change a lot of stuff.

Horses have been the driving force behind empires like the Mongols, they have been used to rapidly relay communications, and probably a great deal more things that I am not aware of.

It sounds like you're excluding the possibility of some other animal becoming more suited to be bred to carry humans - which I think would happen in some way.

Human society wouldn't be impacted to the point of disaster I think, but horses are very useful animals. War is probably the biggest place where a loss would be felt. I imagine that archery would take a much more prominent role as warfare advanced.

If you're planning on looking into this topic further, I'd recommend looking at the civilizations we know of that did not have horses, the Americas as one example.

Answer (score 3):

well, actually we have a couple of civilizations in history that didn't have horses - as they went extinct on that mainland altogether. The Mesoamerica.

And in any case when people needed working animals - they would replace them with others, any suitable: camel, llama, elephant,deer, hippo, rhino, kangaroo, ostrich ... dolphin ... or even predators ... Any animal that has the brains for training and selection will be used ...
Elephants and camels were widely used for military purposes.

Or are they all extinct too? And only primitive insects and reptiles remained ? Well, then it is obvious that the people themselves will become the baggage animal and driving force ... Wider than palanquins, burlaks (barge haulers) on the Volga,mail runners and the like ... etc.
It is curious as well how statues were moved on the Easter Island without horses ...
Perhaps this fact can stimulated the development of mechanisms like Archimede's, and water/wind mills,pigeon and bird mail or optical semaphore etc. But not much faster.
In general, the history wouldn't have changed.

Comment: I agree with most of your thoughts, aside from that "history wouldn't have changed." For one the Mongols would've never arisen, and there were many groups before them that made ample use of the horse and of pack animals. 

In short, it would DRASTICALLY change history. However, I think that in a broader sense, it would not significantly change the way that humanity has progressed through technology. Having a horse does not make it easier to smelt iron - but it does make it easier to haul the ore and transport people who know how to forge it. 

They're helpful, but we could get by without.